# Proving that every Cauchy sequence in measure converges in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $(f_n)$ a sequence of real-valued functions on $X$ which is Cauchy in measure; that is, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$ we have $\mu(\{x\in X \ | \ |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon\})<\epsilon$. Prove that there is a function $f$ on $X$ to which $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in measure.

(Convergence in measure: For any $\epsilon>0,\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(\{x\in X \ | \ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon\})=0.$)

(This is not a homework problem.) I'm finding this very difficult, probably because the definitions are so complicated. I'm not sure how to approach it. Usually when one tries to prove 'Cauchy implies convergent'-type statements it's just a routine application of the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. One approach may be to establish to existence of a Cauchy subsequence for each $x$ but that's more of a guess rather than an idea inspired by understanding. It's just difficult to get a strong enough intuitive understanding for what's going on to solve it. Fixing an $x$ and constructing $f(x)$ individually is not easy as it seems to depend on all the other $f(x)$ as well (measure being a more global property). Any small hints would be appreciated.

Edit: Not sure if this is common thing on StackExchange but I wanted to make a copy of this question myself in order to get a hint for the problem instead of seeing the answer (and spoiling the problem).

Comment: How do you feel about $\infty$?

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: My first thought is to consider that the function $f_n(x)$ can be rewritten as $g(n,x)$, where $g:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then consider the value of $g(\infty, x)$ - but that requires $g(\infty,x)$ to be defined.

Comment: Unfortunately, someone deleted their answer giving a nice sequence of hints for this problem and I am not sure why.

Comment: Convergence almost everywhere implies convergence in measure for finite measures. Your measure is not given to be a finite measure. That may be the reason the answer was deleted.

Comment: Ah I see, yes I was stuck on that part of the proof where you had to deduce convergence in measure and was aware that it only follows immediately from convergence a.e. if the measure space is finite. I was wondering whether that step might be wrong but it looked so well structured that I assume I was just missing something obvious.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy As for saving the argument, firstly, is it not redundant to construct a sequence of measures that tend towards zero ($\leq 2^{-k}$), then take the series of them, which converges, then conclude they tend towards zero? Do we not just scrap the idea of taking the series, or are you referring to a different series? Also, I can't quite see where we should go from there to (I suppose) construct $f$ so that $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f$ in measure.